# how do i limit the length of the input i want inside a Jtextfield?

Tags: java, jtextfield, jformattedtextfield

```
    username = new JTextField("");
    username.setBounds(330, 550, 230, 30);
    username.addActionListener(this);
    username.requestFocus(); // sets focus on JTextField
    this.add(username);
```

Comment: i would like to limit the amount of imput that can be entered in this JTextField. All solutions are welcome, thank you in advance.

Comment: See the Swing tutorial on [Implementing a Document Filter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) for a preferred working solution.

Comment: using a custom Document is an old approach. Since JDK1.4 the preffered approach is to use a DocumentFilter. A filter can be used on any Document that extends AbstractDocument which potentially makes it more reusable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
JTextField username = new JTextField("") ;
final int limit = 10;
username .setDocument(new PlainDocument(){
    @Override
    public void insertString(int offs, String str, AttributeSet a)
            throws BadLocationException {
        if(getLength() + str.length() <= limit)
            super.insertString(offs, str, a);
    }
});
```

Comment: @thynoob I'm creating an anonymous class that extends PlainDocument and @Override is annotation that specify I'm overriding the base class's method. See [this page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html) for annotations in general and the @Override annotation.

Comment: Ok..thanks for the help! ^.^ Do I need @Override in the source code to make it work? And after copy pasting what you suggested I discovered that it didn't work...do I have to add something else?

Comment: @Bala R Oh..turns out I forgot to import something... :P THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! IT WORKED!!!

Comment: Since JDK1.4 a DocumentFilter is the preferred approach.