# Limit the amount of characters typed into a JTextField

Tags: java, swing, validation, input, jtextfield

I figured this would be a simple search on the web but I can't figure this out.  Here is what I'm working with so far.  Ignore the eventHandler, I know its empty.  I want to limit the charField JTextField so that the user can only type one character.  I figured this would be easy because of all the apps that limit the amount of numbers you can type when entering State or Zipcode.

To be clear, I'm not looking to validate input, I'm looking to limit input.  I want it to ignore keystrokes after one character has been entered.

```
package Week6;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Index extends JPanel{

    private JLabel searchLabel;
    private JTextArea searchField;
    private JLabel charLabel;
    private JTextField charField;


public Index(){

    GridBagLayout gridbag = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    super.setLayout(gridbag);

    searchLabel = new JLabel("Enter text to be searched:");
    searchField = new JTextArea("", 5, 20);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(searchField);  

    searchField.setLineWrap(true);
    searchField.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    searchField.setOpaque(true);
    charLabel = new JLabel("Exter a character:");
    charField = new JTextField("", 5);      
    c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;    
    add(searchLabel, c);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;    
    add(scroll, c);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    add(charLabel, c);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 1;
    add(charField, c);  


    CharHandler charhandler = new CharHandler();
    charField.addActionListener(charhandler);   
    }

    class CharHandler implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a `DocumentFilter` for this, take a look at [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [DocumentFilter Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter)

It will allow you to filter out text coming directly before it's applied to the underlying `Document`, which makes it flexible enough to be used with any `Document` implementation that extends from `AbstractDocument`, takes into account the use cases where the user pastes text into the field or calls `setText`

For example...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.print.attribute.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter.FilterBypass;

public class FilterTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FilterTest();
    }

    public FilterTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
                ((AbstractDocument)field.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new SizeFilter(5));

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame.add(field);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    public class SizeFilter extends DocumentFilter {

        private int maxCharacters;

        public SizeFilter(int maxChars) {
            maxCharacters = maxChars;
        }

        public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offs, String str, AttributeSet a)
                        throws BadLocationException {

            if ((fb.getDocument().getLength() + str.length()) <= maxCharacters) {
                super.insertString(fb, offs, str, a);
            } else {
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            }
        }

        public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offs, int length, String str, AttributeSet a)
                        throws BadLocationException {

            if ((fb.getDocument().getLength() + str.length()
                            - length) <= maxCharacters) {
                super.replace(fb, offs, length, str, a);
            } else {
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: is there a way to do it similar to this method which changes lowercase to uppercase?

http://kodejava.org/how-do-i-add-key-listener-event-handler-to-jtextfield/

I figure this would be way less code.  I've also been reading that the Document Filter is an outdated way to accomplish this.

You probably know what you're talking about given your reputation but I'm like that kid visiting the firestation for the first time.  I have to know everything or I won't be able to sleep.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where did you read about *"Document Filter is an outdated way to accomplish this"*?  The link you've provided is actually an INCREDIBLY bad and out-dated approach to the problem, which the `DocumentFilter` was introduced to fix as it can cause mutation exceptions within the underlying `Document`, as the `Document` may still be in a "modifying" state when the key event is triggered.  And SHOULD be replaced with a `DocumentFilter` instead...

Comment: @user3756283 just put `str.toUpperCase()` , where did you read is an outdated way?

Comment: @nachokk I think the OP is talking about converting all text to upper/lower case in real time, which is a perfect excuse for a `DocumentFilter`...

Comment: i refer `str` in `DocumentFilter#insertString` and `replace` :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146274/how-do-i-limit-the-length-of-the-input-i-want-inside-a-jtextfield here is where the guy said that it was outdated.  Then I saw this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21572407/limiting-textfield-inputs so so I figured the guy in the first link was correct.  This looked a lot easier.  I couldn't figure out how to integrate the second link into my code.  I would be so lost without stackoverflow...

Comment: @user3756283 Your linked example also does not take into account what happens if the user pastes text into the field or if you called `setText`, it is a bad example and should be purged from existence, but I don't have the privileges to do that...

Comment: @user3756283 *"using a custom Document is an old approach. Since JDK1.4 the preffered approach is to use a DocumentFilter. A filter can be used on any Document that extends AbstractDocument which potentially makes it more reusable"* - Camickr - Also don't see where they say `DocumentFilter` is out-dated?